# Dependency errors when using Puppeteer (Headless Chrome) with Vue + Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, puppeteer

I'm using these two libraries/templates:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer (Headless Chrome)

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa (Vue template using Webpack and Express).

This is the code:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

    ;(async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22this+is%22')
      const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const stats = document.querySelector('#resultStats')
        return stats.textContent
      })
      console.log(result)
      await browser.close()
    })()
  }
}
```

I did `npm install` many times but I still have dependency errors:

> These dependencies were not found:
>
> - child_process in ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js, ./node_modules/puppeteer/node6/Launcher.js
> - fs in ./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js, ./node_modules/extract-zip/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js and 18 others
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs
>   Listening at http://localhost:8080

Node: I also did `npm install --save child_process fs` many times. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a complaint from webpack regarding built in node modules. Try adding the following to your webpack config...

```
target: 'node'
```

[from the webpack docs...](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/)

> In the example above, using node webpack will compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js require to load chunks and not touch any built in modules like fs or path).

---

Alternatively, you can workaround this with the following...

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty',
  child_process: 'empty'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. And the warning `in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js

81:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Comment: @alex I edited my answer. Try to remove the target and include the edit. Its looking like you are heading in the direction of two bundles, one for the web (vue) and one server side (using puppeteer). Are you able to extract them and communicate over http? e.g. client app now talking to server endpoints that's running some sort of puppeteer logic (think rest api).

Comment: Hanks for the help. I think we're almost there! The app runs but I get this 

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Promise (webpack-internal:///10:223:9)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promisified (`

This is the offending line : `error: nodeFunction.call(null, ...args, callback);`

Comment: @alex wow this is escalating quickly :D [check out this long-running issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/959) which states using the [dedupeplugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin) could be a viable workaround. Are you using webpack 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm using webpack 2 ... so maybe I can't use this plugin.

Comment: I did some searching, I'm unsure, seems to be a common issue though as I see it popping up on various github issue trackers. Let me know if you get any further? This seems to have spiraled a little bit :/

Comment: Check this out too [Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/66)

Comment: I tried the solution in the link of your last comment but I still get the cannot-read-property call error. All right. I'll go to bed defeated for now. I'll post here if I find a solution. Thanks for going an extra mile.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you further right this moment. If you still have trouble, throw together a minified github repository that reproduces this and I'll help you out. Looks like the community over there is having this trouble too so maybe we can resolve it all together

Comment: Right now, the solution is to put the puppeteer code in `dev-server.js` of https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/. Maybe puppeteer is meant to work in a node/express environment, not in a client/webpack enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to bundle up puppeteer for usage in the browser? It's a node-specific module and I doubt it'll work on the front-end. Instead you might try and understand why this file is being bundled and if that's what you are intending to do.